# Element lookup by ID has no result

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

With the Scene Builder 2 I created a scene with following structure:

BorderPane -> SplitPane -> AnchroPane -> SplitPane -> AnchorBane. (http://pastebin.com/7LTNh1Jv)

The AnchorPane in the second SplitPane has the ID *workbench-anchor*. Now I try to get a reference of this AnchorPane via:

```
final BorderPane rootPane = loader.load();
final Node node = rootPane.lookup("#workbench-anchor");
```

But *node* is always NULL.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookups won't work until CSS has been applied, which typically happens on the first frame rendering. You can try performing the lookup *after* showing the stage. You may also be able to force this by calling

```
rootPane.applyCSS();
```

before doing the lookup.

In general, lookups are not a very robust way of finding elements of the scene graph (imho). It's probably better to do any initialization work you need in a controller class, using `@FXML` injections to reference the nodes.

Comment: @JamesD Thanks for the answer! Is there any method which is called automatically in a Controller Class where I can do those initialize stuff?

Comment: The `initialize()` method is invoked after everything is loaded and `@FXML` fields are injected, but before the `load()` method returns. See the [Controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) section of the documentation.

Comment: Is there a reason why the controller class needs to be in the same folder (and not only package) as the FXML file?